# Validating two properties in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have class with such properties:

```
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Finish { get; set; }
```

And such ViewModel:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Start}" />
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Finish}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

I want to enable validation. So, when Start > Finish there must be error. What is the simplest way to provide such validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've found answer myself) I extended my TimeRange class to implement IDataErrorInfo interface like this:

```
public class TimeRange : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Finish { get; set; }


    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    private bool _IsValid()
    {
        return Finish > Start;
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "Start" && !_IsValid())
                result = "Start must occure before Finish!";
            else if (columnName == "Finish" && !_IsValid())
                result = "Finish must occure after Start!";
            return result;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then change my xaml code to:

```
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Start, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
            ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Finish, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
            ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Binding.ValidationRules`.

You can find a MSDN sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx).

Comment: This method validating only one value. And my validation need to compare two properties.

Comment: Add a property which inherits from DependencyObject to your validation class. Add a DependencyProperty to the DependencyObject. Use databinding on the DependencyProperty, and you've got yourself validation that compares two properties.

Comment: @Seekeer, this is a good solution although not well explained. Take a look at my blog post *[Taking data binding, validation and MVVM to the next level - part 1](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2011/07/taking-databinding-validation-and-mvvm.html)*, you can use that for a start and extend it into something quite powerful.

Comment: Thanks! Those two posts are extremely useful!

Comment: @slugster, But here is one problem: I cannot write a Dependency Property in my validation rule class. So I cannot use value of other DatePicker as a parameter...

Answer (score -2):

Compare the values on get. If Start>Finish return null or something.