# WPF Model validation in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm

I've read so far about WPF validation rules and the different approach (using `IDataErrorInfo` , `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, `DataAttributes` and so on), but none matches my needs. I would like to have a model validator which validates the entire view model (I need to set an error if a property has a positive value and another field is set to 1)

What is the best approach for handling this scenario?

Thanks

Update #1: I forget to say I'm under Framework 4.0 and no possibility to upgrade to 4.5

Update #2: I've created a smaller project

Here's my View :

```
<UserControl x:Class="TaskException.Views.SampleView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DropdownList}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding Obj.Sign}">

    </ComboBox>
    <telerik:RadMaskedNumericInput Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding Obj.Qty, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></telerik:RadMaskedNumericInput>

</Grid>
```

My ViewModel :

```
public class SampleViewModel : Screen
{

    private List<DropDownOggetto> dropdownList;

    private DropDownOggetto selectedDropDownList;

    private Dummy obj;

    public DropDownOggetto SelectedDropDownList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedDropDownList;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedDropDownList = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>SelectedDropDownList);
        }
    }

    public List<DropDownOggetto> DropdownList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dropdownList;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dropdownList = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>DropdownList);
        }
    }

    public Dummy Obj
    {
        get
        {
            return this.obj;
        }
        set
        {
            this.obj = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Obj);
        }
    }

    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        Obj = new Dummy
        {
            Qty = 2000,
            Sign = 0
        };

        var lst = new List<DropDownOggetto>();

        lst.Add(new DropDownOggetto { Id = 0, Description = "Buy" });
        lst.Add(new DropDownOggetto { Id = 1, Description = "Sell" });

        DropdownList = lst;
    }

}
```

And the models

```
public class DropDownOggetto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Dummy : IDataErrorInfo 
{
    public int Sign { get; set; }

    public double Qty { get; set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return "Some kind of error";}
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "Qty")
            {
                if (Sign == 0 && Qty < 0)
                    return "Qty must be positive";
                else if(Sign ==1 && Qty >=0)
                {
                    return "Qty must be negative";
                }
            }


            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This simplier sample works almost fine except for the fact that If I've a positive quantity in the RadMaskedNumericInput and I change the dropdown  the validation on the property below is not called... how can I signal it? have I to convert the Sign Qty auto-properties to properties and notify them?

Thanks

Comment: you can always add properties that indicate the *status* of your model to your viewmodel and handle and test everything in it's getter (just don't forget to raise the notification for this property as well)

Comment: Please explain why you are not able to solve this with IDataErrorInfo or ValidationRule with an example code.

Comment: Did you try implement INotifyPropertyChanged for `Dummy ` class so that changes to Qty are notified?

Comment: no they're auto properties since in real app they're filled via Servicestack's Ormlite

Comment: But without Notifyproperty changed implemented in Dummy Class I am not sure you will get the validation will happen. Give it a try hard coding this on the generated class. Then we can see the outcome whether this is the problem

Comment: using the INotifyPropertyChanged worked but I had to put     OnPropertyChanged("Qty"); in the Sign setter.... I don't like it a lot

Comment: True, I have faced the same problem of raising propertyChanged for multiple properties in the same place, couldnt find a good one :). Do let me know if you find one

Comment: Can you try using the `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` instead? Similar to this answer -http://stackoverflow.com/a/8414336/442444? If it works you need not implement NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: This approach works fine on the model but what if I've nested properties? If my Dummy class has a property of type DummyChild which requires validation should also my DummyChild implements INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo? this sucks since I don't like to put in the setter validation logic... the best approach I would adopt would be to use an attribute validation but that cannot refer to another property...